# run maven test with the file of other repository

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing

I have two project, one is java project, another is a configuration project.
now I need to write a unit test to validate the logic of java project, but the configuration file stored at the configuration project.
how could I get the file from other module? I need to create a reader for the file.

Comment: your configuration project also needs to be a maven project, and you use the maven project model to define a dependency between them.

Comment: I found the module which use the both project, and I will write the test in the module